# More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression when UPDATE on multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to update rows in a single table by splitting them into two "sets" of rows.

The top part of the set should have a status set to `X` and the bottom one should have a status set to status `Y`.

I've tried putting together a query that looks like this

```sql
WITH x_status AS (
        SELECT id
        FROM people
        WHERE surname = 'foo'
        ORDER BY date_registered DESC
        LIMIT 5
), y_status AS (
        SELECT id
        FROM people
        WHERE surname = 'foo'
        ORDER BY date_registered DESC
        OFFSET 5
)
UPDATE people
SET status = folks.status
FROM (values
        ((SELECT id from x_status), 'X'),
        ((SELECT id from y_status), 'Y')
) as folks (ids, status)
WHERE id IN (folks.ids);
```

When I run this query I get the following error:

```
pq: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

This makes sense, `folks.ids` is expected to return a list of `ID`s, hence the `IN` clause in the `UPDATE` statement, but I suspect the problem is I can not return the list in the `values` statement in the `FROM` clause as it turns into something like this:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)
(6, 7, 8, 9, 1)
```

Is there a way how this `UPDATE` can be done using a CTE query at all? I could split this into two separate `UPDATE` queries, but CTE query would be better and in theory faster.

Comment: I realize you already have a solution, but I can't help but think there is a better way.  I'm trying to visualize your problem.  Can you include some sample data?  Also, what is REPO?  I can't figure out where that fits in, as I don't see it reference anywhere except the Rvalue of the set.

Comment: Hi, sorry `repo` was a copy paste error I've accidentally introduced. U can come up with some sample data later on. I also suspect this _could_ be done more efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand now...  if I get your problem, you want to set the status to 'X' for the oldest five records and 'Y' for everything else?

In that case I think the `row_number()` analytic would work -- and it should do it in a single pass, two scans, and eliminating one `order by`.  Let me know if something like this does what you seek.

```
with ranked as (
  select
    id, row_number() over (order by date_registered desc) as rn
  from people
)
update people p
set
  status = case when r.rn <= 5 then 'X' else 'Y' end
from ranked r
where
  p.id = r.id
```

Any time you do an update from another data set, it's helpful to have a where clause that defines the relationship between the two datasets (the non-ANSI join syntax).  This makes it iron-clad what you are updating.

Also I believe this code is pretty readable so it will be easier to build on if you need to make tweaks.

Let me know if I missed the boat.

Comment: Yes you got it right -- that's what I'm trying to do. I really like your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So after more tinkering, I've come up with a solution.

The problem with why the previous query fails is we are not grouping the `ID`s in the subqueries into arrays so the result expands into a huge list as I suspected.

The solution is grouping the `ID`s in the subqueries into `ARRAY` -- that way they get returned as a single result (tuple) in `ids` value.

This is the query that does the job. Note that we must `unnest` the `ID`s in the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
WITH x_status AS (
        SELECT id
        FROM people
        WHERE surname = 'foo'
        ORDER BY date_registered DESC
        LIMIT 5
), y_status AS (
        SELECT id
        FROM people
        WHERE surname = 'foo'
        ORDER BY date_registered DESC
        OFFSET 5
)
UPDATE people
SET status = folks.status
FROM (values
        (ARRAY(SELECT id from x_status), 'X'),
        (ARRAY(SELECT id from y_status), 'Y')
) as folks (ids, status)
WHERE id IN (SELECT * from unnest(folks.ids));
```